# Cluster not responding, weird error message

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

My container engine cluster has a red exclamation mark next to its name in the Google cloud console overview of the container engine. A tooltip says "**The cluster has a problem. Click the cluster name for details.**" Once I click the name I don't get any more infos, it's just the usual summary.
Stackdriver doesn't report anything unusual. No incidents are logged, all pods are marked as healthy but I can't reach my services.
Trying to get infos or logs via `kubectl` doesn't work:

```
kubectl cluster-info
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout
```

How can I debug this problem? And what does this cryptic message mean anyway?

Comment: Did you able to resolve this ?

Comment: we've had this problem a few times now... entire cluster gone and has to be rebuilt without any notification or attempt to convey what happened leading up to it "having problems". i think it's really shoddy of google and they've basically replied each time saying that we did something wrong or haven't looked in the right places for information.... i think AWS will be appearing in our not too distant future, can't build a business on shoddy infra like this (nor flippant tech support)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use other `kubectl` commands such as `kubectl get pods`?

This sounds like the cluster isn't set up correctly or there's some network issue. Would you also try `kubectl config view` to see how your cluster is configured? More specifically, look for `current-context` and `clusters` fields to see if your cluster is configured as expected.

Comment: None of the `kubectl` commands worked, that's what I implied with the last sentence before the output of `kubectl`. `gcloud container clusters list` somehow listed the cluster as erroneous but didn't report what was faulty. I ended up deleting and recreating the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was a billing issue. Someone mistakenly disabled the billing profile for our project. We re-enabled it and waited a while, after 20 - 30 mins the cluster came back up with no errors